# "Separate image files" and "Image stack" in MicroManager plugin - easy way to convert between the two?

Tags: imagej

Apologies for tagging this just ImageJ - it's a problem regarding MicroManager, a microscopy plugin for it and I thought this would be best.

I'd recently taken images for an important experiment using MicroManager (a recent version, though I cannot recall the exact number). The IT services at my institution have recently been having some networking problems and my saved preferences for the software had been erased. I'd got half way through my experiment when I realised that I'd saved my images as separate image files (three greyscale TIFFs plus metadata text files) instead of OME-TIFF iamge stacks.

All of my ImageJ macros for image processing rely on having a multiple channel image stack, so this is a bit of a problem. Is there any easy way in MicroManager (or ImageJ) to bulk convert these single channel greyscale images into the OME-TIFF image stack after the images have already been taken?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a [macro](http://imagej.net/Scripting#Getting_started) like this one:

```bs
// Convert your images to a stack
run("Images to Stack", "name=Stack title=[] use");
// The stack will default the images to time points. Convert to channels
run("Stack to Hyperstack...", "order=xyczt(default) channels=3 slices=1 frames=1 display=Color");
// Export as OME-TIFF
run("Bio-Formats Exporter");
```

This is designed to reconstruct one dataset at a time (open 3 images, run the macro and export the `OME-TIFF`).

If you don't want any dialogs to show you can pass an output directory to the Bio-Formats exporter:

```bs
run("Bio-Formats Exporter", "save=/path/to/image.ome.tif export compression=Uncompressed");
```

For the output file name you can get the original image name in the macro with [getTitle()](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html)

There is also a template example on [iterating over all the files](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming#Example_macros) in a directory, if you want to completely automate the macro. However this may take some tweaking since you want to operate on your images 3 at a time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I wanted! Just one more quick question if that's okay:

The image file names are just in the format "img_000000000_[channel]_000.tif" - but they are saved in separate folders with more informative names. Is there a command like getTitle() to easily get the name of the folder they are in, the end of the path? 

I suspect I'll be content to just do three images at a time given its only one dataset, so it's probably easier to just have the dialogue pop up but it'd be good to know.

Comment: @IJQ you can get the containing folder of the current image by running `eval("script", "IJ.getImage().getOriginalFileInfo().directory");`